# SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener override

Tags: android, searchview

I want to override SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener() like this

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="search"
      android:name="search"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      app:actionViewClass="com.dailycaloriediary.autocomplete.MySearchView" />
```

=

```
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    MySearchView mysv = (MySearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    mysv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I've expect if I return `true` in `onQueryTextChange`-method, then according to [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) default behavior is no longer valid and search cannot be perform on typing. But default behavior still present.

How can I override default behavior on typing in SearchView field?

Comment: can you clarify default behavior? do you mean this is still happening for `onQueryTextChange (String newText)` -> `false if the SearchView should perform the default action of showing any suggestions if available` ? as well as `onQueryTextSubmit (String query)` -> `false to let the SearchView perform the default action.`

Comment: Default behavior is perform search on typing in this field. I need to add a delay, I guess it's a right choise to do it by overriding `onQueryTextChange`. But if I simply `return true` request to remote server is still performing on typing.